# Максимальная подстрока и пустая строка

Tags: c#, строки

Всем Привет!

Сделал программу и функцию в ней которая должна делать следующее, ищет в строке подстроку максимальной длины, состоящую из одного и того же символа, и выдает эту максимальную длину.
Например, есть строка " аааббдеггггв ", должно выдаться число 4, потому что есть 4 подряд символа «г», и это максимальная подстрока, где подряд идет один и тот же
символ. Функция работает без учета регистра.

Проблема возникает при наличии пустой строки или пробелов? программа выдаёт 1, как для случая отсутствия вообще одинаковых букв?

думал решить проблему с помощью метода char.IsWhiteSpace но у меня получается только для 1 пробела??

Подскажите пожалуйста как поправить код чтобы учитывал корректно пробелы и пустую строку?

```
    public static int GetMaxLengthSubstring(string s)
    {
        int length = 1;
        int maxLength = 1;

        s = s.ToUpper();

        for (int i = 1; i < s.Length; ++i)
        {
            char currentSymbol = s[i];
            char previousSymbol = s[i - 1];

            if (currentSymbol == previousSymbol)
            {
                length++;

                if (length > maxLength)
                {
                    maxLength = length;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                length = 1;
            }
        }

        return maxLength;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Длина максимальной подстроки в строке 45645555645456 = " + GetMaxLengthSubstring("45645555645456"));
        Console.WriteLine("Длина максимальной подстроки в строке аааббдеггггв = " + GetMaxLengthSubstring("аааббдеггггв"));
        Console.WriteLine("Длина максимальной подстроки в строке 112233555 = " + GetMaxLengthSubstring("112233555"));
        Console.WriteLine("Длина максимальной подстроки в строке Эйяфьятлайокудль = " + GetMaxLengthSubstring("Эйяфьятлайокудль"));
        Console.WriteLine("Длина максимальной подстроки в строке аааббдегГггв = " + GetMaxLengthSubstring("аааббдегГггв"));
        Console.WriteLine("Длина максимальной подстроки в строке аааббдегГггв = " + GetMaxLengthSubstring("  "));

        Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте [string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.isnullorwhitespace?view=netframework-4.8):

```
public static int GetMaxLengthSubstring(string s)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))
    {
        return 0;
    }

    int length = 1;
    int maxLength = 1;

    //...
}
```

**UPD.** Для проверки символа в строке на пробельный используйте [char.IsWhiteSpace(currentSymbol)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.iswhitespace?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Андрей Спасибо большое за ответ! Лучи Благодарности!
Подскажите пожалуйста насколько применять конструкцию if (!char.IsWhiteSpace(currentSymbol) || !char.IsWhiteSpace(previousSymbol)) для проверки на пробелы в данном контексте?

Comment: @IgorM вам нужно исключить пробелы в середине строки?

Comment: да чтобы функция их пропускала при проверке, потому что char их учитывает, как символ
я добавил внешнее условие if (!char.IsWhiteSpace(currentSymbol) || !char.IsWhiteSpace(previousSymbol)) вроде работает но может я не прав??

Comment: @IgorM все верно, только вам не нужно проверять предыдущий символ, только текущий.

Comment: Спасибо огромное за помощью!!!! Лучи Благодарности !!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
var text = "аааббдеггггв";

var count = 0;

foreach (var letter in text.Distinct().ToArray())
{
    var temp = text.Count(chr => chr == letter);
    if (count < temp)
        count = temp;
}

Console.WriteLine($"Максимальное количество подряд идущих букв {count}");
```

вот решение которое на много меньше по коду и работает правильно

Comment: Денис, Спасибо большое за ответ! Но нам нельзя этим функционалом пользоваться пока((((( как то через char и прочее нужно сделать, голову поломал уже(((

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int GetMaxLengthSubstring(string s)
{
    int length = 0, maxLength = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < s.Length; ++i)
    {
        char currentSymbol = s[i];
        char previousSymbol = s[i - 1];

        if (currentSymbol == previousSymbol)
        {
            length++;

            if (length > maxLength)
                maxLength = length;
        }
        else
            length = 1;
    }

    return maxLength;
}

Console.WriteLine("Длина максимальной подстроки в строке Эйяфьятлайокудль = " + GetMaxLengthSubstring("аааббдеггггв ".ToLower()));
```